# Can't write to xml after manipulating the file

Tags: xml, asp-classic

First I write the XML file with classic ASP. Then I can read, write, and modify as needed. Then I want to copy the file into another directory for use with another system. If I move the file, it works. If I copy and paste the file it tells me "Access is denied". I can read them, but cannot write to the files. Any help or suggestions?

Comment: I belive IIS has limited access rights to directories outside the folder the app is running.

Comment: The app can write to the file, as long as I have not used any other program to manipulate it.

Comment: Maybe after you manipulate it you save it with different permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your xml file read-only? Look at the premissions on your created xml. Try to write another xml with different name and track if problem is still the same.

Comment: I thought that too, but it is not set to read only, and it happens no matter what I call the file.